# Nginx bloquear|redirecionar arquivos da url

Tags: php, regex, nginx

Estou criando um encurtador de url em meu subdomínio ex: (go.domain.com) para servir de referencia externa, exemplo:

```
// a url de uma pagina (extensa)
www.domain.com/user-2124532544454343dgfs-pages-artes-31234124141241241212xxxx

// ficaria assim:
go.domain.com/world-arts
```

Bom este exemplo ta bem "tosco" mas o problema é que necessito receber a url via `$_GET` no subdomínio "go" e como a url "encurtada" aponta para um subdiretório em "go" uso `try_files` com enfase em diretórios `$uri/` nas configurações do server block `nginx` para concluir o processamento da requisição ex:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?l=$request_uri;
}
```

Onde "l" (location) é a referencia para acessar o `$_GET` com `PHP` e buscar no banco de dados para que se existir registro redirecionar.

Até ai tudo bem uma vez que a url "encurtada" seja acessada corretamente más quando se lança por exemplo "go.domain.com/image.png" cai no erro `404` contudo `404` esta reservado para um erro (notfound) global dentro do projeto.

Como verificar se na url possui ponto (.) ou outro carácter inválido em qualquer parte dela? E assim retornar a index com um `$_GET` para pegar esse erro?

O mais próximo que cheguei foi com esta regra:

```
error_page 400 /index.php?error=bad;

location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|html|htm)$ {
   return 400;
}
```

Contudo não é possível prever todas as possibilidades, um simples /hgaasd.aaa seria suficiente para lançar um erro 404.

No caso em questão os caracteres permitidos seriam: alfa-numéricos e **@_-**

Comment: Resumindo você que uma regra para que no final tenha apenas `/alfa-numéricos e @_-`? isso?

Comment: E que eu possa lançar as entradas não compatíveis em um erro que não seja 404